# Is it possible to automatically resume playing after the category of AVAudioSession is set to playback or soloAmbient?

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I play music in my app using AVAudioPlayer.

In a particular view controller, I need to record audio. In the `viewDidAppear(_:)` of the view controller, I set the category of the AVAudioSession.shared to `.record`. In the `viewDidDisappear(_:)`, I set the category of the AVAudioSession.shared to `.soloAmbient`.

When the category is set to .record, the music stops playing as expected.
However, when the category is reset back to `.soloAmbient`, the music does not resume playing. I need to manually call `play` method on the `AVAudioPlayer` object to start playing.

Is it possible for `AVAudioPlayer` to resume playing automatically when the category is reset back to `.soloAmbient`?

Comment: If you are playing music, the category should not be solo ambient.

Comment: The music that is played is background music. However, the issue mentioned in the question occurs even if the category is set to playback.

Comment: I don't see why it's an issue. You are the one recording and playing. Nothing needs to happen automatically.